# PS3: command not found bash

Tags: linux, bash, select, case

I am working on a multi-level menu for a script. I've looked at lots of sites for advice on the select and case statements I'm using. I've been making sure to check for the ;; at the end of each case etc. and I am stuck with what is the problem with the code.

I keep getting these 2 errors when trying to run the file 'PS3: command not found' and 'syntax error near unexpected token `('`options =  ("Repository_Options" '.

I am new to Bash so any help is appreciated, thanks!

```
PS3="Select an operation:"
options=("Repository_Options" "Log_Options" "Text_Editor" "Exit)"
select choice in "${options[@]}"
do
case $choice in
    "Repository_Options")

        PS3="Select an operation: "
        options1 =("Access_Repository" "View_Files" "Edit_Files" "Compile_Files" "File_Logging" "Exit")
        select choice1 in "${options1[@]}"
        do
            case $choice1 in

                "Access_Repository")
                    echo "Accessing Repository..."
                    access_repository;;

                "View_Files")
                    echo "Printing files..."
                    view_files;;

                "Edit_Files")
                    edit_file;;

                "Compile_Files")
                    compile_project;;

                "File_Logging")
                    echo "Logging files..."
                    file_logging;;
                "Exit")
                    break;;
                *)
                    echo "Invalid input";;

            esac
        done

    "Log_Options")

        PS3="Select operation: "
        options2=("Create_Log_File" "Add_User_Comments" "Exit")
        select choice2 in "{$options2[@]}"
        do
            case $choice2 in

                "Create_Log_File")
                    echo "Creating log file..."
                    create_log_file;;

                "Add_User_Comments")
                    add_user_comments;;

                "Exit")
                    break;;
                *)
                    echo "Invalid input";;
            esac
        done
    "Text_Editor")

    echo "edit text";;

    "Exit")
        echo "Exiting"; break;;
    )*
        echo "Invalid input";;
    esac


    echo "Select an operation: "
done
```

Comment: Add a shebang and then paste your script there: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: `options=("Repository_Options" "Log_Options" "Text_Editor" "Exit)"` is improperly quoted.

Comment: "PS3: command not found" indicates you have spaces in the assignment, like `PS3 = something` -- no spaces allowed around the equal sign.

Comment: "unexpected token '('" indicates you are using /bin/sh instead of /bin/bash -- arrays are a bash feature

Comment: Also see [How to use Shellcheck](http://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck), [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/56041) (U&L.SE), [How to debug a bash script?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/951336/608639) (SO), [How to debug bash script?](http://askubuntu.com/q/21136) (AskU), [Debugging Bash scripts](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_02_03.html), etc.